# RSA Message too long Javascript JSBN

Tags: javascript, rsa, public-key-encryption, jsbn

I am using JSBN in javascript to encrypt a set of string (message) of facebook data to securely send them to my server (PHP) and decrypt them there.

Some users are experiencing "Message too long" on something like

```
"&fbemail='+fbemail+'&gender='+fbgender+'&birthday='+fbbirthday+'&name='+fbname+'&surname='+fbsurname+'&fbuser='+fbuserid"
```

I have generate a private key through:

```
$privateKey = openssl_pkey_new(array(
          'private_key_bits' => 1024,
          'private_key_type' => OPENSSL_KEYTYPE_RSA,
        ));
```

Why am I getting that message? The message is not that long.

I have looked at the following post, yet I dont understand how to use AES in javascript without having the AES passphrase compromised.

[RSA Encryption Problem [Size of payload data]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5866129/rsa-encryption-problem-size-of-payload-data)

Comment: Could you not simply do AJAX over HTTPS?

Comment: Are you using a `GET` request?

Comment: Marcel - Yes i am using GET on my server.

Comment: You can make a hybrid encryption with [crypto-js](https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/#AES) for AES encryption, and [window.crypto.getRandomValues](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.crypto.getRandomValues) for getting cryptographically random keys.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without generating a symmetric key and encrypting the full message? Use a bigger key. 1024-bit keys can only encrypt 117 bytes without some sort of padding, but a 2048-bit one can handle up to 245 bytes, and a 4096-bit key up to 501 bytes. That could make your script handle bigger and accented names (non-ASCII characters uses two or more bytes per character).

I ended up with a similar problem, but Thoman Pornin answer to [RSA Encryption Problem [Size of payload data]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5866129/rsa-encryption-problem-size-of-payload-data) was great in explaining the reason of this limitation.

Also gave up trying to split up the message in several encrypted chunks after reading (the same) Thomas Pornin answer to [Does RSA padding have to be unpredictable if the payload is?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1793/is-rsa-of-a-random-nonce-with-no-padding-safe/1799#1799)