# rsa routines::data too small for key size, rsa routines::data too large for key size

Tags: node.js, encryption, cryptography, rsa

I am getting an errors when I used `crypto.constants.RSA_NO_PADDING` respectively.

```
node:internal/crypto/cipher:79
    return method(data, format, type, passphrase, buffer, padding, oaepHash,
           ^

Error: error:0200007A:rsa routines::data too small for key size
    at Object.publicEncrypt (node:internal/crypto/cipher:79:12)
    at Object._encryptFile (C:\Users\GB\Documents\projects\customprojects\numericalarrays\pickler\node_modules\hasher-apis\src\hasher.js:260:28)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\GB\Documents\projects\customprojects\numericalarrays\pickler\demos\demos.jscertificate.pickle.js:44:49)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1149:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1203:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1027:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:868:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
  library: 'rsa routines',
  reason: 'data too small for key size',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_RSA_DATA_TOO_SMALL_FOR_KEY_SIZE'
}

Node.js v18.10.0
```

I am getting error when I used `crypto.constants.RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING`.

```
node:internal/crypto/cipher:79
    return method(data, format, type, passphrase, buffer, padding, oaepHash,
           ^

Error: error:0200006E:rsa routines::data too large for key size
    at Object.publicEncrypt (node:internal/crypto/cipher:79:12)
    at Object._encryptFile (C:\Users\GB\Documents\projects\customprojects\numericalarrays\pickler\node_modules\hasher-apis\src\hasher.js:260:28)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\GB\Documents\projects\customprojects\numericalarrays\pickler\demos\demos.jscertificate.pickle.js:44:49)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1149:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1203:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1027:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:868:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
  library: 'rsa routines',
  reason: 'data too large for key size',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_RSA_DATA_TOO_LARGE_FOR_KEY_SIZE'
}

Node.js v18.10.0
```

This is the encrypt file function

```
function _encryptFile(remotePath, remoteDestPath, algorithm = "sha256", keyAlgorithm = "rsa", digest = "base64", keyOptions = { modulusLength: 2048 }, options = { modulusLength: 2048 }) {
    const crypto = require('crypto');
    let data = fs.readFileSync(remotePath, { encoding: options.encoding ? options.encoding : "utf-8", flag: "r" });

    algorithm = algorithm || "sha256";
    keyAlgorithm = keyAlgorithm || "rsa";
    digest = digest || "base64";
    keyOptions = keyOptions || { modulusLength: 2048 };
    options = options || { modulusLength: 2048 };

    const { privateKey, publicKey } = _genKeyPair(keyAlgorithm, keyOptions);

    let encrypted = crypto.publicEncrypt({
        key:  publicKey,
        padding: crypto.constants.RSA_PKCS1_PADDING,
        oaepHash: algorithm
    },
        Buffer.from(data)
    ).toString(digest);

    fs.writeFileSync(remoteDestPath, encrypted);
    return {
        privateKey: privateKey,
        publicKey: publicKey,
        encrypted: encrypted
    }
}
```

This is the deencrypt file function

```
function _decryptFile(remotePath, remoteDestPath, privateKey, algorithm = "sha256", keyAlgorithm = "rsa", digest = "base64", options = { modulusLength: 2048 }) {
    const crypto = require('crypto');
    let hashdata = fs.readFileSync(remotePath, { encoding: options.encoding ? options.encoding : "utf-8", flag: "r" });

    algorithm = algorithm || "sha256";
    keyAlgorithm = keyAlgorithm || "rsa";
    digest = digest || "base64";
    options = options || { modulusLength: 2048 };

    let decrypted = crypto.privateDecrypt({
        key: privateKey,
        padding: crypto.constants.RSA_PKCS1_PADDING,
        oaepHash: algorithm
    },
        Buffer.from(hashdata, digest)
    );

    fs.writeFileSync(remoteDestPath, decrypted);
    return {
        decrypted: decrypted.toString("utf-8")
    }
}
```

```
function _genKeyPair(keyGenType = "rsa", options = { modulusLength: 2048 }) {
    const crypto = require('crypto');
    const { privateKey, publicKey } = crypto.generateKeyPairSync(keyGenType, options);
    return { privateKey, publicKey }
}
```

This is the encrypt decrpt file usage of the functions function

```
// Hash P3 File to P3
let { privateKey, publicKey, encrypted } = hash.encrypt(p1, p1, "sha256", "rsa", "base64", { modulusLength: 2048 }, { modulusLength: 2048 });
// let { privateKey, publicKey, encrypted } = hash.encrypt(p3, p1);
console.log("[hasher._fileHash]: File hashed");
console.log(encrypted);


// DeHash P3 File hashed content to P3
let r3 = hash.decrypt(p1, p1, privateKey, "sha256", "rsa", "base64", { modulusLength: 2048 });
// let r3 = hash.decrypt(p1, p1, privateKey);
console.log("[hasher._fileHash]: File dehashed");
console.log(r3);
```

This is the contents of the file for `I do not get` data too large for key size`:

```
1. C
2. C++
3. Java

This is a file containing a collection of interpreted programming languages.
1. Python
2. Nodejs
3. Ruby
```

This is the contents of the file for I do not get `"data too small for key size"`:

```
1. C
2. C++
3. Java
```

I do not get the error when I use `"crypto.constants.RSA_PKCS1_PADDING"`. What is the issue here and how do I get the buffer length right for dynamic use cases?

Comment: With RSA only a limited amount of data can be encrypted, namely key size minus a space depending on the padding. For PKCS#1 v1.5 padding this is 256-11=244 bytes for a 2048 bits key, for OAEP it depends on the digest, for SHA256: 256-66=190 bytes. RSA without padding is insecure, so this is not an option. For encryption of larger amounts of data, hybrid encryption should be used: The data is encrypted with a symmetric encryption (e.g. AES) and the symmetric key with an asymmetric encryption (e.g. RSA).

Comment: @Topaco thank you. that was of real help. what is the max for rsa like algorithms. is there a list of max bytes for all algorithms in crypto.getCiphers and crypto.getHashes?

Comment: The value to subtract from the key size is 11 bytes for PKCS#1 v1.5 padding (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5868456/9014097)) and for OAEP depends on the digest (see [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/42100) for different digests).

Comment: thank you very much. can you add this as an answer?

Comment: You're welcome. I have put my comments as an answer.

Comment: just one more check. these are my keyoptions `{ modulusLength: 2048,   publicKeyEncoding: {  type: "pkcs1",  format: "pem",  },  privateKeyEncoding: { type: "pkcs1", format: "pem",   }  }` I am getting an error when doing file write `writeFileSync("public.pem", publicKey.toString('hex'))` and the err is `data size too large` `library: 'rsa routines',   reason: 'data too large for key size', code: 'ERR_OSSL_RSA_DATA_TOO_LARGE_FOR_KEY_SIZE'`

Comment: For a more detailed analysis, you would need to create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example): In particular, remove the file I/O for the test so that the code can use the data directly instead of files. Also complete the code so that it is executable (currently e.g. `_genKeyPair()` is missing). Also post the function calls with all the input data required by the code. With this, the issue should be reproducible on my side.

Comment: there was noting much in the genkeypair. but if i use the commented options with `publicKeyEncoding: {  type: "pkcs1",  format: "pem",  }` and try to dump the key to a file the error happens. but the key generated works fine.

Comment: I didn't suspect a bug in `_genKeyPair()`, the function is simply required for the code to be executable. In the current code I don't find a key export, so this seems to be a separate problem. Generally the export works, see here: https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/EyT, which is why it is necessary to present a code with which the failure can be reproduced. Regarding the export you should ask a new question, for further questions about the current code please post an executable code as said, so that the problem is reproducible. Thx.

Comment: no i tried that. when i did `publickKey.export().toString("hex")`, it gave me an error saying no function called export. second when i tried `publickKey.toString("hex")` it worked and was able to console out and write to a file. i have `publicKeyEncoding: {  type: "pkcs1",  format: "pem",  }` in the creation.

Comment: If `publickKey.toString("hex")` really works, then `publickKey` is not a `KeyObject`. However, in your code from the question, `publicKey` is a `KeyObject`, so I don't see the connection. Here you can find a sample code for your two functions without file I/O: https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/ECF. As you can see the code is executable and encryption, decryption and key export work. If you have further questions, please post a corresponding example, with which your problems can be reproduced!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When encrypting with RSA, you always have to use a padding for security reasons. The length of the message plus padding can be at most as large as the key size (or the modulus in bytes). Since the padding has a minimum length, this results in a maximum message length that is equal to the key size minus the minimum length for the padding.

For PKCS#1 v1.5 padding ([RSAES-PKCS1-v1_5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8017#section-7.2)) the minimum length of the padding is 11 bytes. A 2048 bit key can therefore encrypt a maximum of 256 - 11 = 244 bytes, see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5868456).

For OAEP ([RSAES-OAEP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8017#section-7.1)), the minimum length of the padding depends on the OAEP digest and is `2 * (hLen + 1)`, where `hLen` is the output size of the digest in bytes.
For SHA-1 with an output size of 20 bytes, the minimum length of the padding is therefore 42 bytes, for SHA-256 with an output size of 32 bytes it is 66 bytes.
A 2048-bit key can therefore encrypt a maximum of 256 - 42 = 214 bytes for OAEP/SHA-1 and a maximum of 256 - 66 = 190 bytes for OAEP/SHA-256, see also [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/42100) for a tabular overview of the maximum message length depending on different key sizes and digests.

---

For larger messages, encryption is usually not done with RSA, but with [hybrid encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem), see also [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/14). For this, the data is encrypted with a symmetric algorithm, e.g. AES, and the symmetric key is encrypted with an asymmetric algorithm, e.g. RSA.

Comment: just one more check. these are my keyoptions `{ modulusLength: 2048,   publicKeyEncoding: {  type: "pkcs1",  format: "pem",  },  privateKeyEncoding: { type: "pkcs1", format: "pem",   }  }` I am getting an error when doing file write `writeFileSync("public.pem", publicKey.toString('hex'))` and the err is `data size too large` `library: 'rsa routines',   reason: 'data too large for key size', code: 'ERR_OSSL_RSA_DATA_TOO_LARGE_FOR_KEY_SIZE'`